# How do I exit tail --follow on ERROR or FATAL log level

Tags: linux, logging, tail

I `tail -f` the log file of one of my services, but I would like to automatically stop my tail process once my logger has printed any content starting with OR containing **ERROR** or **FATAL**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: in case your service process terminates after the error, simply call `tail -f --pid=<your-service-pid>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To terminate `tail -f` immediately after the output has a line containing ERROR or FATAL, try:

```
tail -f file.log | awk '{print} /ERROR|FATAL/{exit}'
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file.log 
abc
def
ghi
ERROR
jkl
mno
pqr
$ tail -f file.log | awk '{print} /ERROR|FATAL/{exit}'
abc
def
ghi
ERROR
```